# pasting code in python a persistent problem, is there a simple solution? (tabs vs spaces)

Tags: python

I have always struggled with python because of the white space debate... tabs vs spaces.

I prefer tabs set at 8 spaces.  I also like nintendo over sega and coke over pepsi and Beatles over Elvis.  I suppose 4 spaces is not the worst thing in the world.

One of my biggest misunderstandings about python is how to keep code straight when pasting large chunks of code from one source into another body of code.

It is quite difficult to know where groups and logic start and stop when pasting code chunks around in python.  Once a large body is pasted, how does one make sure things are correct in a code editor, especially when the length is multiple pages?

For instance, un-indenting a group can cause massive changes to logic in python.

Is there a trick that I'm missing?

It would seem that c++ or ecma syntax had this solved.

**let me revise this... I'm not looking for a good text editor... there are many!

It's more of a question about WTF in python because all whitespace philosophy aside, I don't know how people are copying and pasting code around when whitespace depth mistakes can cause major problems!

Comment: What text editor/code editor/IDE do you use?

Comment: Well, depending on my location or context, anything from default vim to Qt creator to gedit to textedit, to anything else that works.

Comment: This will probably get closed as off topic, but jumping on board the 4 space train will only help your copy-paste issues, and an editor with multi-line indent and dedent support (typically shift+tab) is crucial, imo.  Lastly, if you're pasting multiple page code segments, (a) you probably don't need to adjust their indentation, or (b) you probably shouldn't bother with their code (it's very rare that respectable code is that long, in a single file, and somehow needs to be adjusted as you describe).

Answer (score 0):

There is no trick, top level code has no indent, a block of code whether `function`, `class`, any loop has the same indentation, any children block in it (a `while`, `if/else`, `for` loop or `with`, gets another level of indentation until it's done, then goes back to its parent.
As long as the type of indent & number of space/tab are consistent, that's all the rules. You just have to make sure those are correct when copy pasting.